# Modify a stored procedure to display the latest role for an employee

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a stored procedure which returns the 3 months' data for an employee. I have to modify the procedure in such a way that while displaying the role of the employee is his role in the latest month.

If for the latest month, the data does not exist, then the previous month's role is displayed.
The table has an identity column (PK), `EMP_ID`, `Role` and various other columns. But for answering this question, this much data is sufficient, I hope.

Comment: It would be better if you posted some sample data along with the relevant columns of tables from which you pull data. You could also give the example of the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

It would have been better if you posted sample code. Anyways, check this out. It may give you what you want. The code inside procedure should look something like this .

```
select
id_column
, emp_Id
,(select top 1 role from table_name where emp_id=@emp_Id and role is not null order by your_date_Column desc )
,col1
,....
,coln
from Table_Name where emp_id=@emp_id
```

Comment: select Role from DP_Project_GMA_Staffing where Month=(select MAX(MONTH) as Latest from DP_Project_GMA_Staffing where Month in (month(DATEADD(MM,-1,GETDATE())),month(DATEADD(MM,-2,GETDATE())),month(DATEADD(MM,-3,GETDATE())))) and FK_Project_ID='<PROJECT_ID>' and Fiscal_Year=2012 and Emp_Id='<emp_id>' and Plan_Effort_Curr_Month=(select MAX(Plan_Effort_Curr_Month) from DP_Project_GMA_Staffing where Month=(month(DATEADD(MM,-1,GETDATE())))  and FK_Project_ID='<PROJECT_ID>' and Fiscal_Year=2012 and Emp_Id='<EMP_ID>')

Comment: Im looking for the answer similar to the lines of the above query. The query if fine for the present month, but if the present month=JANUARY-2011, then i should be able to get the data for oct, nov and dec 2011, which im not.